# Why doesn't this regex work when mapping to hash?

Tags: javascript, regex

Curious why this doesn't work. I have went thru many different permutations, but overall this is what I am trying to do and can't get it to work.

Basically, use the hash key to find match, then use that key to get the value with the hash reference.

```
 var arr = {'blah':'WULLVERT','misc':'DUDETTER'};
 var test_string = "maryLou is misc &&& such a cool mary blah dude yeah wullvert";
 test_string = test_string.replace(/(jQuery.map(reg,function(k,v){return v}).join("|"))/gi,arr["$1"]);
 test_string;
```

of course, when I use string literals.. this works: (though still can't use the $1 for the hash reference).

```
     test_string = test_string.replace(/(blah|msic)/gi,"$1_proofofconcept");
```

Comment: You seem to have JavaScript code inside RegExp delimeters. Is that intentional? Perl has a `/e` mode, but JavaScript does not.

Comment: 1) Use the RegExp constructor. 2) `"$1"` will not work in the replacement pattern like this, you need a replacement callback: `var rx = new RegExp('(' + jQuery.map(arr,function(k,v){return v}).join("|") + ')', 'gi'); test_string.replace(rx, function(full_match, m1) { return arr[m1]; })`

Comment: I tried the RegExp construtr, but that didn't work either. Let me revisit it and test again. thanks. OK, I left off the literal '(' etc.. thanks, but now my second issue.. why can't I reference the hash value ala arr[$1]

Comment: ahh, ok. I didn't realize you had to have the callback. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Just to be clear, you _can_ use `$1` in a string. `arr[$1]` doesn't work because it's code. That's why it needs a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `new RegExp(..)` to dynamically generate regular expression object.

```
var arr = {'blah':'WULLVERT','misc':'DUDETTER'};
var test_string = "maryLou is misc &&& such a cool mary blah dude yeah wullvert";
test_string.replace(
    new RegExp(jQuery.map(arr,function(v,k){return k}).join("|"), 'gi'),
    function(x) { return arr[x]; }
);
// => "maryLou is DUDETTER &&& such a cool mary WULLVERT dude yeah wullvert"
```

Comment: thanks. Like DC above mentioned, I also didn't realize the use of the callback. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hey False, I have a question for you -- can you pass the actual regex expression to the callback that matches? so, lets say I had in the hash as a key - "\\?+" : "questionMark" : so I want "\\?+" to be passed into the callback, possible?

Comment: @jamesemanon, The code in my answer: `function(x) { return arr[x]; }`, here `x` is matched string. Do you mean this?

Comment: no, I wasn't succinct enough with my second question. In my previous question lets say that pattern: "\\?+" matched "?????" in some string. I try to match arr[????] <-- that is not a valid key. In other words, trying to use more complex regex as the keys. This is probably a bit tricky. I was hoping to pass in the context of the match, not what it matched. Of course, you DID answer my original question :-) , I just thought to add an additional one.

Comment: @jamesemanon, Escape special characters (that have special meaning when used in regular). Then pass it to `RegExp`. See [How to escape regular expression in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2593661/2225682). Is this what you want?